# iOS how to get Email contacts from Mails app?

Tags: ios, abaddressbook

My application needs to send email to friends.

I found that Mail application has much more Email address than the Contact app. In Mail app or MFMessageComposeViewController, I can search for email dress from any mail that contact me before.

My question is how to retrieve those emails address to my app?

Best,

Kong

Answer (score 2):

No you can only acces contact via the [Address Book API](http://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/#documentation/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007744) this is the same API that [`MFMessageComposeViewController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMessageComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html) uses.

Apple does not allow any acces to other app's data because of security restrictions.

Comment: Thanks, I'm afraid of a NO, too. Still, I want to wait if there has other work-arounds. If not, then I'll mark this is the correct answer.

Comment: Any work arounds will probably contain private API wich will get you app reject if you plan to submit it to the app store.